# How to retrieve a single result and make sure it is returned?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using a criteria which is expected to return a single record. How can I find out the criteria returns a value and retrieve the returned record, I am using the following code but not sure if there is any more efficient way.

In this case I have to check the list size, if it is more than zero means it returned something, then need to retrieve the first one.

```
List<Users> mylist = new ArrayList();

Criteria cre = --------
.......
mylist = (Lists<Users>) cre.list();

if(mylist.size() > 0) {   // cre returned a record

    System.out.println(mylist.get(0).getName());

}else {  //nothing has been returned

    System.out.println("no result is returned");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use [uniqueResult](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#uniqueResult%28%29):

```
Criteria cre = -----
MyObject obj = cre.uniqueResult();
if (obj != null) {
  System.out.println(obj.getName());
} else {
  System.out.println("Nothing found");
}
```

Please be aware though that if there is more than one matching result, a `HibernateException` is thrown...

Answer (score 2):

`Object a = criteria.uniqueResult();` will work. But if your criteria returns more than one value then you get Exception.

My recommendation is `criteria.list();`.